# template to show figures javascript/php

Tags: javascript, visualization

I am working on a website with financial charts. The charts are made with Highcharts. Until now highcharts was suficient but now i would like to show just single figures on a page, designed figures with shapes and colors. I have searched on the internet js template to display figured but each time it s payable or i have to use it with Git. It s a very simple website and i would like to find free and simple to use temolates, do you know where i can find it please ?

Thank you very much if you read this post!

Comment: single figure on a page? just set width height to 100% and remove all other elements!

Comment: Hello! Asking questions about off-topic ressources is considered off-topic here. Please refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).